# Elasticsearch geohash_grid returns 1 doc count but query returns a lot

Tags: elasticsearch, geohashing

I'm using Elasticsearch 5.1 with geohash_grid query as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    ...
    "geo_bounding_box":...
  },
  "aggs": {
    "lochash": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "currentShopGeo",
        "precision": 5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And here is the results of elasticsearch:

```
{
  ....,
  "aggregations": {
    "lochash": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "w3gvv",
          "doc_count": 1  // only 1 doc_count
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I used "w3gvv" to decode geohash and have a bounding box as below following "w3gvv".

```
{
  "top_left": {
    "lat": 10.8984375,
    "lon": 106.7431640625
  },
  "bottom_right": {
    "lat": 10.8544921875,
    "lon": 106.787109375
  }
}
```

However, when I use the returned bounding box above to search for the document inside, it appears that Elasticsearch returns 13 items more. Anyone have any idea why it is so weird?

Comment: Can you also show the query at the top, specially the `geo_bounding_box` one?

Comment: `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_bounding_box": {
            "type": "indexed",
            "currentShopGeo": {
              "top_left": {
                "lat": 10.8651173923467,
                "lon": 106.591202952246
              },
              "bottom_right": {
                "lat": 10.7605769974159,
                "lon": 106.791360117773
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    ...
  }
}` => { "key": "w3gvv", "doc_count": 1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution,
We could use geo_bounds to know the exact boundary of the clusters that are returned by Elasticsearch as below:

```
"aggs": {
  "lochash": {
    "geohash_grid": {
      "field": "currentShopGeo",
      "precision": 5
    },
    "aggs": {
      "cell": {
        "geo_bounds": {
          "field": "currentShopGeo"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result should be:

```
{
   "key": "w3gvv",
   "doc_count": 1,
   "cell": {
     "bounds": {
       "top_left": {
          "lat": 10.860191588290036,
          "lon": 106.75263083539903
       },
       "bottom_right": {
          "lat": 10.860191588290036,
          "lon": 106.75263083539903
       }
     }
  }
 }
```

It appears that the results shows exactly where the item is.

Comment: if this solution is working for you then please mark it as an answer